# Can't handle route. Component doesn't show up

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I want the component MovieList to show up after the filter got applied. When I click the button the path changes to something like /search/anime?sort=popularity and then I suppose to see a MovieList component. However, it shows no sign of presence.

```
function MovieFilter({ history }) {
      const [sort, setSort] = useState('');

      const onChangeFilter = e => {
         setSort(e.target.value)
      };

      const applyFilter = () => {
        history.push({
           pathname: '/search/anime',
           search: sort ? `?sort=${sort}` : ''
       });
     };

    return (
       <>
        <FormControl>
            <Select value={sort} onChange={onChangeFilter}>
                <MenuItem value='Popularity'>Popularity</MenuItem>
            </Select>
            <Button onClick={applyFilter}>Apply filter</Button>
        </FormControl>

        //<Route path={`/search/anime?sort=${sort}`} component={MovieList} />
    </>
   )
 };
```

Here's my routing. I tried it instead of putting Route at the end of MovieFilter component.

```
 <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
        <Route path='/search/anime?sort=Popularity' component= 
        {MovieList} />
        <Route path='/search/anime' component={MovieFilter} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: Is the `Route` under [Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Router)? Without it, the Route component won't render.

Comment: @dance2die Yes, I tried different options.

Comment: "/search/anime" and "/search/anime?sort=Popularity" correspond to the same route, I think the queries params should be handled inside the component.

Comment: @miguelps Ok, but isn't it doesn't suppose to work with hardcoded values? I thought it should work when I directively tell the route to correspond some query. In my case it's   <Route path='/search/anime?sort=Popularity' component= 
        {MovieList} /> instead of <Route path={`/search/anime?sort=${sort}`} component={MovieList} />

Comment: As I understand, that will work only on the route it self, ex: "/search/anime/:anime_id/", here you define a component to handle routes that match this url. But you can't define to query params because queries can be arbitrary.

Comment: In your case, I think it doesn't work because the second route with "/search/anime" will override the first one